# Using an API with Servicem8 software

Tags: api-design

I want to build/use 2 separate APIs to work in with servicem8 software. What would be the best way to go about this and is it difficult to implement?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The best place to start would be to read the ServiceM8 Developer docs - https://developer.servicem8.com/